# What is wrong with this div & image creating JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, createelement

I know little about JavaScript but, as with everything I do, I'm throwing myself headfirst into some complex code (at least *I* think it's complex).
The code is basically designed to fit as many (approx.) 300x200 images into a div called "supercontainer".
A div called "container" is supposed to be created and then this is supposed to be populated with images.
The images will be resized slightly to make them fit in more aesthetically and nr of rows and columns are calculated also.
I'm not so concerned about how the logic of calculating number, or size, or position of images (or boxes) works, because I think this is sound.
I'm more concerned with my syntax and use of javascript language itself because literally nothing is displayed at the moment.
The 'setupboxes' function is called within my 'index.php' and I'm pretty sure I couldn't have got that wrong.

See below the .js code:

```
function setupboxes() {
    var stdbw=300; //standard box width
    var stdbh=200; //standard box height
    var w=document.getElementById("containerparent").clientWidth; //get width of containerparent
    var h=document.getElementById("containerparent").clientHeight; //get height of containerparent
    var b=10; //set containerparent padding
    var p=b; //set box padding

if(w>999) {
        b=20; //set containerparent padding to 20px if screen width over 999px
        p=b; //set box padding to 20px if screen width over 999px 
 } 
    var nrcols=Math.round((w-2*b)/(stdbw+2*p)); //set integer for nr of columns
    var nrrows=Math.round((h-2*b)/(stdbh+2*p)); //set integer for nr of rows
    var nrboxes=nrcols*nrrows; //calculate nr of boxes
    var bh=(((h-2*b)/nrrows)-2*p); //set box height
    var bw=(((w-s*b)/nrcols)-2*p); //set box width
    var top=(h-(nrcols*(bh+2*p))); //set distance of container from top of containerparent
    var left=(w-(nrrows*(bw+2*p))); //set distance of container from left of containerparent
    var conth=((nrcols*(bh+2*p))+2*b); //set height of container
    var contw=((nrrows*(bw+2*p))+2*b); //set width of container
    var divcont=document.getElementById('containerparent').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div id="container"></div>');  //create container
    divcont.style.position = 'relative';
    divcont.style.top = top;
    divcont.style.left = left;
    divcont.style.border = 'red 1px solid';

    var nrboxesit=nrboxes;
    var boxnr=1;

    while(nrboxesit>0){ //create boxes
        document.getElementById('container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img src="images/0000001.jpg">');
        img.style.padding = p;
        img.style.height = bh;
        img.style.width = bw;
        boxnr=boxnr+1;
        nrboxesit=nrboxesit-1;  
    }
 }
```

Like I say I'm new to JavaScript so please don't assume I would have known to try some simple fixes!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, i'm guessing you are not waiting for the window onload event? where do you call the script inside your php? You can open the developer tools of your browser with F12 (mostly) and add a `debugger;` statement inside your setupboxes function

Comment: I didn't go through all of your code, but sizing style values have needed an unit (like `px`) for a long time, values are not pixels by default.

Comment: There should be at least an error or two in your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). (`p` not defined, then `s` not defined). Don't ignore those. Also, you can't use the result of `insertAdjacentHTML()` as an element.

Comment: well, for 1, s is undefined where you calculate bw

Comment: ah ... s should have been 2 ...

Answer (score 0):

I made the minimum number of changes to get images to display. Specifically I didn't know what 's' stood for, so I set it equal to 10.

`divcont` is assigned to the element before attempting to insert HTML to it.

`img` near the end is undefined, I assigned an id and used that for a reference. Perhaps you won't want to wastefully assign ids like that.

```js
 function setupboxes() {
   var stdbw = 300; //standard box width
   var stdbh = 200; //standard box height
   var w = document.getElementById("containerparent").clientWidth; //get width of containerparent
   var h = document.getElementById("containerparent").clientHeight; //get height of containerparent
   var b = 10; //set containerparent padding
   var p = b; //set box padding

   // FIXME
   var s = 10;

   if (w > 999) {
     b = 20; //set containerparent padding to 20px if screen width over 999px
     p = b; //set box padding to 20px if screen width over 999px 
   }
   var nrcols = Math.round((w - 2 * b) / (stdbw + 2 * p)); //set integer for nr of columns
   var nrrows = Math.round((h - 2 * b) / (stdbh + 2 * p)); //set integer for nr of rows

   var nrboxes = nrcols * nrrows; //calculate nr of boxes
   var bh = (((h - 2 * b) / nrrows) - 2 * p); //set box height
   var bw = (((w - s * b) / nrcols) - 2 * p); //set box width
   var top = (h - (nrcols * (bh + 2 * p))); //set distance of container from top of containerparent
   var left = (w - (nrrows * (bw + 2 * p))); //set distance of container from left of containerparent
   var conth = ((nrcols * (bh + 2 * p)) + 2 * b); //set height of container
   var contw = ((nrrows * (bw + 2 * p)) + 2 * b); //set width of container

   // FIXME
   var divcont = document.getElementById('containerparent');
   divcont.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div id="container"></div>'); //create container

   divcont.style.position = 'relative';
   divcont.style.top = top;
   divcont.style.left = left;
   divcont.style.border = 'red 1px solid';

   var nrboxesit = nrboxes;
   var boxnr = 1;

   while (nrboxesit > 0) { //create boxes

     // USED PLACEHOLDER IMAGE HERE

     document.getElementById('container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img id="myBox' + nrboxesit + '" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">');

     // FIXME img is undefined. I just added an id based on
     // current iteration of box number 
     var img = document.getElementById('myBox' + nrboxesit);
     img.style.padding = p;
     img.style.height = bh;
     img.style.width = bw;
     boxnr = boxnr + 1;
     nrboxesit = nrboxesit - 1;
   }
 }

 setupboxes();
```

```html
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 600px; height: 600px;" id="containerparent">
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 600px; height: 600px;" id="container">
        </div>
    </div>
```